# What is the purpose of Vih and Vil in the comparator's datasheet?

Tags: comparator, logic-level

Looking into the [MAX999](http://www.redrok.com/Comparator_MAX961-MAX999_5nS_5mV_Latch_R-R_3V-5V.pdf) datasheet I can not figure out how to utilize information given for the Vih and Vil

```
Logic-Input High --- Vih --- (Vcc/2 + 0.4) min
Logic-Input Low  --- Vil --- (Vcc/2 - 0.4) max
```

The rest of datasheet says nothing about inputs' ability to be configured as logic inputs - it is the output which is logic level. What is the purpose of this information then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's for the logic inputs: SHDN - shutdown; and LEA - Latch-Enable Input -

When SHDN is high, the MAX961/MAX963/MAX964/MAX997 is shut down.

The MAX961/MAX963 include internal latches (ie the LEA) that allow storage of comparison results.

The MAX999 doesn't have any of these logic inputs.

Comment: I hate when they overload the datasheet with many parts. It's not like it costs anything to print a datasheet.

Comment: it is easier for a manufacturer to maintain one datasheet for a family of very similar parts, though. Particularly as they may all use the same silicon design in different packages and/or with laser trimmed variances. So you can see their predicament if you've worked on documentation in similar situations. Doesn't bother me, personally.

Comment: @TonyM This might have been true in the past but in these days with databases and software etc.

Comment: oh, forget the past, I'm describing today :-) Try maintaining this stuff, loads of documents are a big workload.